# ElementNotVisibleException in Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have a problem with Selenium WebDriver throwing ElementNotVisibleException for the element being loaded in a pop-up window even though when instantiating the WebDriver I use:

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Occurs for Chromedriver and IEDriver

Comment: Is the popup javascript alert or some element inside the page?

Comment: it's an overlay on the page

Comment: It sometimes happens when the element is always on page, but its hidden by javascript. Then sometimes WebDriver thinks that its still hidden. Will have to investigate on it how do I solve it...

Comment: it seems that WebDriver ignores `implicitlyWait` - stack trace shows "command duration or timeout: 31 miliseconds"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems that solution was quite simple:

```
WebElement cBoxOverlay = wait.until(ExpectedConditions
            .visibilityOf(driver.findElement(By.id("cboxOverlay"))));
```

Driver waits to load the cBox and then tries to find the close button

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. In case anyone else is wondering, you'll first need to do something like this, in order to call wait: WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 100);